# write some html and js to a iframe,not working in IE:$ is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I write some html and js to a iframe,not working in IE7/8/9,the error message is:$ is not defined?

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){
            var data='<html>\
                          <head>\
                              <meta charset="utf-8">\
                              <title>Demo</title>\
                              <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>\
                              <script type="text/javascript">\
                                    $(function(){\
                                        alert("abc");\
                                    });\
                              <\/script>\
                          <\/head>\
                          <body>\
                          </body>\
                      </html>';
            window.frames["code_result"].document.open(); 
            window.frames["code_result"].document.write(data);
            window.frames["code_result"].document.close(); 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="code_result" frameborder="0" class="frame_result" name="code_result"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

who can tell me why?thanks

**update**

this error only show in IE78/9,it work well in Chrome and FireFox

Comment: What's the version of your IE? I've tried your codes, and it works on Chrome and IE9

Comment: I just copied and pasted this into a document on my desktop and ran that in Google Chrome & IE9 with no error.

Comment: Could you access http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js directly?

Comment: this error only show in IE78/9,it work well in Chrome and FireFox

Comment: @allentranks yes,and it can work well in Chrome and FireFox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the code loading the I frame content. It's ie's loading order. Simply wrap your I frame script in a window onload function so it allows jquery to load first. Tested and working in ie.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
 $(document).ready({
    alert('123');
 });
```

Comment: :i get error in chrome:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

You will need it load jquery in the I frame before running code. JQuery hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: I don't think so. The iframe is able to load jQuery from 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'.

Comment: The link to jQuery is in the text being written to the iframe