# Iframe contents get html in IE is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I used below code to create an iframe:

```js
Ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
document.body.appendChild(Ifrm);
IfrmBod = $(Ifrm).contents().find('body');
IfrmBod.append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Append jquery function not work correctly in ie for this example .
Finally
When I use `IfrmBod.html()`, it works fine in Chrome but not in IE. In IE `IfrmBod.html()` is undefined.

Comment: Does it work well in other Browsers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527582/write-some-html-and-js-to-a-iframe-not-working-in-ie-is-not-defined

Comment: Please Do Not Capitalise Every Word In A Sentence. It Is Very Irritating To Read

Comment: In FF And Chrome Work Fine !

Comment: You didn't tell us which version of IE or what doctype you're using; both could be relevant.  For example, if you're using `<!DOCTYPE html>` (or another doctype that leads to edge mode), you may be running into parsing issues with that capitalized markup.

Comment: I have this problem in ie9

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by settimeout.

Is there a better way?

```
Ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
Ifrm.style.width = "100%"; 
Ifrm.style.height ="100%"; 
document.body.appendChild(Ifrm);
setTimeout(function(){
IfrmBod = $(Ifrm).contents().find('body'); 
...
},50);
```